# No parameterless constructor defined for this object during deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap

The code has DependencyInjection and already have all the required implementation. I am able to run in my machine as well as deploy in a test server. But when it is deployed in client machine where it is part of a main site. This is where this exception happens. I don't have control over this server, so clueless.

Any idea what might be going on here? Could it be the main site has a lower version of DependenyInjection that causes this error? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Maybe the code for the object that can't get created, the DI configuration code, etc.?

Comment: your controllers should instantiate by IoC at runtime, make sure that you have your custom dependency resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't register your custom dependency resolver:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver());
```